# Publish Yeoman generator on npm

Tags: npm, yeoman

I have created a simple Yeoman generator to scaffold a angular typescript app.

I'd like to publish is as a npm package to share it with my team.

I have used yo to create the generator and locally it all works as expected.

I cd to the generator folder in the terminal and run `npm publish` to pubish the generator.

This works and I can see the generator on npm.

If I than run `npm install -g generator-at-test` I get a list of warnings in the terminal like

`npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running remove acorn@3.3.0 node_modules/generator-at-test/node_modules/acorn`

The yo generator does not appear in the list of generators when I run `yo` in the terminal.

The npm package can be found here https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-at-test

I can only leave it up 24 hrs but then I'll have to delete it.

Comment: I installed your generator globally and i can see `At Test` generator when i run `yo` command.

Comment: OK, I'm confused then, I can't install the generator